Is there an equivalent of Bash shell printf %q in C?
Bash shell built-in function printf has the format specifier %q that will:
> quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input

Example (Bash shell):
printf '%q' "abc\ndef"

... will print:
abc\\ndef

Is there an equivalent format specifier for C's printf?

No, there isn't.

Why would C need it? It doesn't have any way of reusing that as input -- there's nothing that reads input and parses quotes and escape sequences.

@Barmar: There are C programs that generate C code, such as lex and yacc.

OK, there's a use. But there's nothing built into C to do it.

bash's printf is itself implemented in C, so of course an implementation exists (under GPL licensing terms -- GPLv2 if you take it from bash 3.x or earlier, GPLv3 from bash 4.0 onwards). Mind, I'm tempted to call needing it a smell -- keeping code and data well separated from each other should prevent any call for such a thing. What's the use case? (If you're generating a shell command, f/e, you can have it use data passed out of band, either in environment variables or argv elements).

If you're trying to start a new process using one of the exec functions, you don't need to do this.

If you do find yourself in the awkward situation of having to escape a shell word in C, you can just wrap it in single quotes and escape each inner single quote with '\''. It's not as human readable, but it's correct.

C doesn't have any functions pertaining to bash or any other shell. Specifically, it doesn't have a builtin way to create a bash string literal that produces a given string.
It is, of course, possible to write such a function in C. A quick and dirty implementation of such a function would both prepend and append ' to the given string after replacing every instance of ' with '\''.
That said, there are often better alternatives to generating shell code. Passing data to code/commands can be done using arguments, environment variables, pipes, files, etc.

Note that this produces quoting suitable for interpretation by a standardish unix shell, but not necessarily for anything else. For example, if you wanted the string quoted for inclusion in C source, you'd have to do it quote a bit differently. PowerShell? Different. JSON? Different. Etc...

@Barmar Re "%q doesn't surround the output with quotes.", I never said it did. I said it produces a bash string literal that produces the given string.

@Barmar Re "its output is basically the C string literal syntax for the input string.", No, it's a bash literal for the input string, like I said in my answer. /// Re "e.g. newline => \n", No, it doesn't. That would be wrong since \n produces two characters in bash. A newline is actually converted to $'\n'.

@Barmar, Re "Your "quick and dirty" is missing most of this.", No, it doesn't. It just creates a different but equivalent literal. Yes, it's not as clean as the one %q does, but I did say that.

ikegami's suggestion should work, according to the POSIX standard (e.g. for sh and bash). If you want exactly the same behavior as bash's printf %q, just copy-paste its implementation (licensed under GNU GPL 3). First printf inspects the string and then calls either ansic_quote (resulting in $'...') or sh_backslash_quote (resulting in a\ b).
